# How do I decode data from a TCP socket

Tags: java, python, sockets, tcp, chat

I am trying to make a very simplistic chat program with a server made in python and the client in java. However I have no idea how to decode the data which the server receives from the client. The client sends and encodes to UTF-8.

Just printing it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAxHL.jpg

And decoding from UTF-8 first it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXMph.jpg

I assume that the NUL character or \x00 can be removed. the same going for the b'' which wraps the entire message. The second character seems to specify the length of the message. But how do I decode this? Should I just remove characters manually? I know this is quite a basic question and has probably been asked before but I don't even know what to search for.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I'm sending UTF-8 encoded messages over a TCP connection. Is there anything else I'm doing or should be aware of?

Comment: To echo what @ejno said, it looks like you are using some kind of structured binary data encoding, *not* simply UTF-8 text. From the samples you gave, one can see at least some text strings preceded by 16-bit lengths. In general, to "decode data from a TCP socket" (or from anything else), you need to follow the specification of whatever format you expect the data to be in.

Comment: In the java client I have a DataOutputStream object which i use with this method: out.writeUTF(input);

Comment: Well, CLEARLY according to [the documentation of that method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeUTF%28java.lang.String%29), it doesn't write UTF-8 to the output stream. It says "First, two bytes are written to the output stream", which explains your 16-bit lengths that precede the strings. And even after that it doesn't write UTF-8, it writes in Java's own idiosyncratic encoding which it calls [Modified UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Modified_UTF-8) and which is a actually variant of [CESU-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CESU-8), not UTF-8.

Comment: So first of all, you need to clarify what format exactly you wish to use to communicate between the client and server: the protocol. Is it plain UTF-8? Is it the bizarre structured encoding that `writeUTF` emits? Is it something else? Then write both your client and server to follow that specification.

Comment: Ooh I see. I didn't expect java to be doing something else (I didn't really have a clue what UTF-8 was to begin with) than what the method name said. I will try to patch that up somehow, thanks for the help. Will you put this as an answer to the question?

Comment: OK, I can put that as an answer. With regard to the name of the method, I think the Java designers were cheeky when they called the method `writeUTF` and not `writeUTF8`. The latter would be an outright lie; the former only suggests that the method might emit UTF-8.

Comment: Heh, tricked by the developers... I'll try to write my own function to decode whatever they did I think. Thanks for the help once again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In the java client I have a DataOutputStream object which i use with this method: out.writeUTF(input);

According to the [documentation of that method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeUTF%28java.lang.String%29), it doesn't write UTF-8 to the output stream. It says "First, two bytes are written to the output stream", which explains your 16-bit lengths that precede the strings. And even after that it doesn't write UTF-8, it writes in Java's own idiosyncratic encoding which it calls [Modified UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Modified_UTF-8) and which is a actually variant of [CESU-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CESU-8), not UTF-8.

So first of all, you need to clarify what format exactly you wish to use to communicate between the client and server: the protocol. Is it plain UTF-8? Is it the bizarre structured encoding that `writeUTF` emits? Is it something else? Then write both your client and server to follow that specification.